# Обтекание вложенного div по элементу

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Имеется два `div`.

У div c `id="block1"` задана ширина и меняется автоматически в зависимости от ширины экрана.

У div c `id="block2"` ширина не задана.
Как можно сделать, чтобы у этого div было обтекание по тексту или любому другому элементу?

Сейчас у него ширина такая же, как у div c `id="block1"`.

```css
#block1{
  width:35%;
  background:green;
  color:#ffffff;
}
#block2{ 
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <p>Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <div id="block2"><p>Привет fff Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Как насчёт float?

Comment: Ширина блока с `id="block2"` должна заканчиваться у края текста. А сейчас цвет фона доходит до конца первого блока.

Comment: Не получится... Наверное. Вот если бы внутри переноса не было, то можно было бы что-то придумать.

Comment: Да вообще какие-то некорректные условия .... без заданной ширины этот блок в любом случае будет стремиться к 100% родителя .... флоат тут вполне будет работать, просто либо надо ширину ограничивать, либо блок должен содержать то что не будет растягивать этот блок (не длинный текст допустим)

Comment: @MedvedevDev Ну во втором блоке и будет содержаться только не длинный текст.

Comment: Дима, ну тогда я не вижу никаких проблем с тем, что бы использовать float, осталось только выяснить что означает ваша фраза "Ваш float бьёт всю верстку" - если речь про то, что родитель перестает обращать внимание на размеры дочернего (зафлоаченного) элемента, то есть .clearfix или overflow: hidden;

Comment: @MedvedevDev Пробовал ".clearfix или overflow" до того, как задать вопрос, не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Давай тогда разбираться на примере ... чем именно плох флоат?

```css
#block1{
  width:35%;
  background:green;
  color:#ffffff;
}

#block1:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#block2{
  float: right;
  background:red;
}

.block2_content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <p>Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <div id="block2">
    <div class="block2_content"></div>
   </div>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>
  <p>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</p>

</div>
```

Comment: `.block2_content {width: 100px;height: 100px;}` - так я и сам знаю:) Надо бы, чтобы ширина облегала по тексту, т.е. ширина будет резиновой. Поменяю текст на чуть больше и в ширину уже может не влезть.

Comment: я же тебе это и написал, что этот блок всегда будет стремиться к 100% ширины родителя, не бывает магической пыли которая заставляет быть блоки тех размеров при которых они будут лучше смотреться ... все знакомые дизайнеры так размышляют, но такого в нашей вселенной не бывает. либо фикс ширина, либо max-width, иначе ты не заставишь блок "Будь классным"!

Comment: Ok, понял! Спасибо!